# How to Deserialize a JSON array in Csharp

Tags: json-deserialization

Below is Json payload i am fetching from a API:

```js
[
  {
    "id": "8c0e33ea-51af-44e0-8cb5-ef93703a4e6c",
    "storeId": "xyz",
    "name": "009DI",
    "styleColors": []
  },
  {
    "id": "f6284195-0f58-4f6b-a3b8-d5d22d1f7e63",
    "storeId": "abc",
    "name": "A001A",
    "styleColors": []
  }
]
```

Classes created for deserialization:

```cs
    public class BINobjects
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "binid")]
        public string binid { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "storeId")]
        public string storeId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "binname")]
        public string binname { get; set; }       
    }
    public class BINdetails
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "BINobjects")]
        //public pages pages { get; set; }
        public IList<BINobjects> BINobjects { get; set; }        
    }
```

Below is how I am trying to de-serialize it as a List of BINdetails objects

```cs
BINobjects BINdetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BINobjects>>(result);
```

Error:
cannot implicitly convert 'system.collections.generic.list to "tools.binobjects'. However, below code works but reading only 1 column from source.
`var str = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BINobjects>>(result);`
Is there a way to read directly into the object than into a variable. I am fine with whatever that works.

Comment: You haven't specified what's not working with the code you've posted. Could you edit your post to clarify what your expected behavior is, and what the code is currently resulting in?

Comment: updated the section.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by editing the class property names:

```
public class BINobjects
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string binid { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "storeId")]
        public string storeId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
        public string binname { get; set; }

    }
```

And then reading into variable:

```
var str = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BINobjects>>(result);
```